# How can I use Ionic Appflow with a Quasar + Capacitor project?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, quasar-framework, ionic-appflow

I'm using quasar framework (https://quasar.dev/) to build a hybrid app. I'm interested in trying out ionic appflow to do live updates.

However, that requires that the project is an ionic project (e.g. if I run `$ ionic link`, it gives the error that my project is not an ionic project).

So how can I make my quasar project an ionic project as well, or is there some other way to use appflow?

Answer (score 3):

To pass that error you have to run `ionic init` first and choose “Custom” when it ask about the framework. Then you can run `ionic link` without problems.

Then, since quasar have a “strange” project structure, you have to tell appflow more about it. So you have to create a `appflow.config.json` file with this content:

```
{
    "apps":
    [
        {
            "appId": "yourAppflowAppId",
            "root": "src-capacitor",
            "dependencyInstallCommand": "cd .. && npm install",
            "webBuildCommand": "cd .. && npx quasar build -m capacitor -T ios --skip-pkg && npx quasar build -m capacitor -T android --skip-pkg"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: If you use yarn or other package manager replace `npm install` with the appropriate install command for your package manager.

Note 2: If you only want to do a web build for live updates you can modify the `webBuildCommand` script for only running the iOS or android build instead of both, or if you only are developing for iOS or android remove the platform you don’t support. If you support both and plan to do native builds in appflow too, then keep both.