# Quasar framework project and Appflow

Tags: vue.js, capacitor, quasar-framework, ionic-appflow

I'm creating a mobile app with Quasar framework and capacitor. I'm trying using Appflow to be simple to create and publish our app in the store (and test it). However, appflow expects the capacitor.config.json file be in the root directory but quasar adds a subfolder called src-capacitor and add all content inside. I try read the documentation of appflow and try multiple things but I always get the same error "native type is capacitor but capacitor.config.json is not available: this should not have happened". Appflow said that works with any other capacitor project but nothing mentions to change the capacitor file location when building. Someone had the same problem or something similar? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66095757/how-can-i-use-ionic-appflow-with-a-quasar-capacitor-project/77224404#77224404 ? Not too specific but probably can help

Comment: Yes I check but not really helpful. It's really inside appflow when building the project